# PHP - Trying to get the text only inside quotes

Tags: php, regex, slack

Im trying to make a Slack slash command using a PHP script.

So when I type:

```
/save someurl.com "This is the caption"
```

I can convert that one string into two different variables.

The long string will come in as:

```
https://someurl.com "This is the caption"
```

I want to be able to turn that into:

```
$url = https://someurl.com;
$caption = This is the caption;
```

I've tried some regex patterns from previous searching here on Stack Overflow but could get anything to work correctly.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

If you know it will be in that format, you can use something like this:

```
(\S+)\s+"(.+?)"
```

Sample code:

```
$string = 'someurl.com "This is the caption"';
preg_match('~(\S+)\s+"(.+?)"~', $string, $matches);
var_dump(
    $matches
);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  string(33) "someurl.com "This is the caption""
  [1] =>
  string(11) "someurl.com"
  [2] =>
  string(19) "This is the caption"
}
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/eX2mH6/2).

This works by matching one or more non-whitespace characters (`(\S+)`), one or more whitespace characters (`\s+`), a `"`, one or more characters in a non-greedy fashion, then another `"`.

Comment: The caption that gets returned with your regex is as follows:

`
$slackMessage = "'" . $_POST['text'] . "'";
$regexPattern = '~(\S+)\s+(.+)~';

preg_match($regexPattern, $slackMessage, $matches);
$link = $matches[1];
$title = $matches[2];
`

Comment: @MattLewis Your last comment doesn't show the problem, but (from your now-deleted comments) it looks like you have a Unicode smart quote in there rather than a straight, normal quote. The simplest way to get around this is to use this regex: `(\S+)\s+\S(.+?)\S`. Please try that and let me know if it works.

Comment: I'm getting an error: `preg_match(): Unknown modifier '\' `



$regexPattern = '(\S+)\s+\S(.+?)\S';

Comment: @MattLewis You still need the delimiters (`~`, in this case), as in `~(\S+)\s+\S(.+?)\S~`. I didn't mean to remove those. So, the actual line of code would be `preg_match('~(\S+)\s+\S(.+?)\S~', $string, $matches);`

Comment: No problem, Im very new to PHP. I think when we add the single quotes around the original string its breaking the url that I need to work. I'm getting an error when my other function is running to get information based on that url.

`Warning:  file_get_contents('http://somurl.com): failed to open stream`

Comment: @MattLewis I'm not adding any single quotes around the original string. That's just so that I can show you legitimate sample code. I'm going off of your statement, `The long string will come in as: ...` If you don't actually know how to get the data in that format, that's a very different issue.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following regex

`(.*?)\s"(.*?)"`

Then use the matching groups to get what you want.

Example :

```
$string = 'https://someurl.com "This is the caption"';

preg_match('/(.*?)\s"(.*?)"/', $string, $matches);

print_r($matches);
/* Output:
Array
(
    [0] => https://someurl.com "This is the caption"
    [1] => https://someurl.com
    [2] => This is the caption
)
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach:

```
<?php
$string = 'https://someurl.com "This is the caption"';
$regex = '~\s+(?=")~';
# looks for a whitespace where a double quote follows immediately
$parts = preg_split($regex, $string);
list($url, $caption) = preg_split($regex, $string);
echo "URL: $url, Caption: $caption";
// output: URL: https://someurl.com, Caption: "This is the caption"

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Slack, but if it is possible to input something like:
`/save someurl.com "This is a \"quote\" in the caption"`

Resulting in this long string:
`https://someurl.com "This is a \"quote\" in the caption"`

Then a lazy pattern looking for a double quote will fail.

Irrespective of that, greedy patterns are more efficient than lazy ones, so I would recommend the following for all scenarios:

```
~(\S+) "(.+)"~
```

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/RK3J1))

```
$input = 'https://someurl.com "This is a \"quote\" in the caption"';
list($url, $caption)=(preg_match('~(\S+) "(.+)"~', $input, $out) ? array_slice($out,1) : ['','']);
echo "url: $url\ncaption: $caption";
```

Output:

```
url: https://someurl.com
caption: This is a \"quote\" in the caption
```